# Azure DevOps release task - Extract the value of the picklist option from input field

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

We have an Azure DevOps release task, a snippet of the task.json file is like this:

```
"instanceNameFormat": "Test Task - $(category)",    
"inputs": [
    {
        "name": "category",
        "type": "pickList",
        "label": "Choose Category",
        "required": true,
        "helpMarkDown": "Select Category",
        "options": {
            "a": "Category A",
            "b": "Category B"
        }
    }...
```

Now as you can see, we have a picklist, and based on the selection, we are populating the instance name(i.e. the name of the task that shows up on the task list). Now, since the key in options are 'a' and 'b' and not the full name, the task shows up as 'Test Task - a', whereas what we want is 'Test Task - Category A'. How can we achieve it? I tried `$(category.name)` and `$(category.value)` but neither worked.

Comment: why dont you just replace "a" with "Category A"?

Comment: Does Lu's answer help you? If so,please mark it, this will help people with the same issue.

Comment: That might help for a stand-alone case, but I have some logic and comparison based on "a", i.e. options key in the same file below, hence putting a space in the identifier defeats the purpose.

Answer (score 0):

The `instanceNameFormat` is how the task will be displayed within the build or release step list, you can use variable values by using $(variablename). If you want to set the value, you need to implement the script. Please refer to the [azure-devops-extension-tasks](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-extension-tasks).

You can create a script file and add the code as following:

```
    // Get category
    const inputCategory = tl.getInput("category", false);
    tl.setVariable("category", inputCategory);
```

Here, the method *setVariable* will set the input value to variable named **category**.

Comment: But the script will run during run-time, I want this to happen when the user is filling up the details in release task dynamically.

Comment: I don't think it is possible to do that. Currently there is no way to reference the display name portion from a picklist in the instance name format.